# Achieving CContainedWindow-like functionality without superclassing or sublcassing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, atl

Let's say you'd like to have a `CContainedWindow`, but you'd like to work from a clean slate--i.e., you want it to have its own fresh message map, without any super or subclassing.  So  in other words, you want the convenience of having all of your handler methods in a single class declaration, but you don't want to have to deal with any idiosyncrasies of a predefined window class. Is there an elegant way to accomplish that?  The only thing I've come up with that's sort of in the ballpark is something like this (it's a nested `CWindowImpl`-derived class within an outer `CWindowImpl`-derived class):

```
class COuterWindow :
    public CWindowImpl<COuterWindow>
{
public:
    COuterWindow() : m_wndInner(this)
    {
    }

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(COuterWindow)
        // ...
    END_MSG_MAP()

private:
    class CInnerWindow :
        public CWindowImpl<CInnerWindow>
    {
    public:
        CInnerWindow(COuterWindow* pwndOuter) : m_pwndOuter(pwndOuter)
        {
        }

    private:
        COuterWindow* m_pwndOuter;

        BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CInnerWindow)
            MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT, m_pwndOuter->OnInnerPaint)
            // ...
        END_MSG_MAP()
    };

    LRESULT OnInnerPaint(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&);

    CInnerWindow m_wndInner;
};
```

This works, but I was wondering if there's anything in the ATL I'm overlooking (like a message map macro or something) that would accomplish this or make it neater or allow use of a single message map. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You may be looking for `CHAIN_MSG_MAP_DYNAMIC` and [`CDynamicChain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cdynamicchain-class). It would allow you to redirect all  (or most) messages from an instance of `CInnerWindow` to an alternative message map in an instance of `COuterWindow`.

Comment: Thanks, but am I right in concluding from the docs that you can only redirect to a default message map?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/message-map-macros-atl?view=vs-2019#chain_msg_map_dynamic

Comment: No, `CDynamicChain::SetChainEntry` takes the ID of an alt message map.

Comment: Oh, awesome.  I didn't see that.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've made a proposed solution, but I was wondering if you knew how to templatize this (so it accepts things like `CWinTraits`).  Do you have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Igor's comment, I think you can do something like this to achieve a sort of "blank" `CContainedWindow`:

```
class CContainedWindowBlank : public CWindowImpl<CContainedWindowBlank>
                            , public CDynamicChain
{
public:
    CContainedWindowBlank(CMessageMap* pObject, DWORD dwMsgMapId = 0)
    {
        SetChainEntry(1, pObject, dwMsgMapId);
    }

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP()
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP_DYNAMIC(1)
    END_MSG_MAP()
};
```

Although I'm not sure how to turn this into a template that accepts things like `CWinTraits`.  If anyone knows how to do that, I'd appreciate the input.  Thanks.

Actually, I seem to have achieved the templated version, although I'm not quite sure why it works or whether it could be simplified:

```
template <class TBase = CWindow, class TWinTraits = CControlWinTraits>
class CContainedWindowBlankT : public CWindowImpl<CContainedWindowBlankT<TBase, TWinTraits>, TBase, TWinTraits>
                             , public CDynamicChain
{
public:
    CContainedWindowBlankT(CMessageMap* pObject, DWORD dwMsgMapId = 0)
    {
        SetChainEntry(1, pObject, dwMsgMapId);
    }
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP()
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP_DYNAMIC(1)
    END_MSG_MAP()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to simply register a blank window class, the ordinary Win32 way, and then use it in conjunction with `CContainedWindow`. Perhaps something like this in a header file:

```
#define WC_BLANK L"BLANKWINDOWCLASS"

inline const ATOM atom = [](){
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpszClassName = WC_BLANK;
    wc.hInstance = _AtlBaseModule.GetModuleInstance();
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}();
```